# How to make one table row expand outside width of the rest of the table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a HTML table and the final row needs to expand the full width of the page, while the rest of the rows are centered with a margin on the left and right like so:

```
#mytable {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
}
```

Is this possible?

```css
#mytable {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
}

#mytable th,
#mytable td {
  padding: 0.8em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#mytable th {
  background-color: #6699FF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#last-row {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Columna</th>
      <th>Relative</th>
      <th>Isso</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>This</td>
      <td>Column</td>
      <td>Is</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Column</td>
      <td>two</td>
      <td>this</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>is</td>
      <td>not equals</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>the</td>
      <td>Column</td>
      <td>real</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="last-row">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>first</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Column</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zvjaep1q/

Comment: Not in standard table markup.  You've either got to use some non-table liners inside cells, or do an "overlay" within a div, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use colspan to bridge columns.

```css
#mytable {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
}

#mytable th,
#mytable td {
  padding: 0.8em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#mytable th {
  background-color: #6699FF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#last-row {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Columna</th>
      <th>Relative</th>
      <th>Isso</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>This</td>
      <td>Column</td>
      <td>Is</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Column</td>
      <td>two</td>
      <td>this</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>is</td>
      <td>not equals</td>
      <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>the</td>
      <td>Column</td>
      <td>real</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="last-row">
      <td colspan="4">5
      first
      One
      Column</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```